# Should my IoT device poll with HTTP or listen with TCP?

Tags: asp.net, sockets, http, tcp, .net-micro-framework

I'm creating an IoT Device + Server system using .NET Micro Framework and ASP.NET WebAPI (Probably in Azure).

The IoT device needs to be able to frequently update the server with stats whilst also being able to receive occasional incoming commands from the server that would change its behaviour. In this sense, the device needs to act as both client and server itself.

My concern is getting the best balance between the security of the device and the load on the server. Furthermore, there must be a relatively low amount of latency between the server needing to issue a command and the device carrying it out; of the order of a few seconds.

As I see it my options are:

- Upon connection to the internet, the device establishes a persistent TCP connection to the server which is then used for both polling and receiving commands.
- The device listens on a port (e.g. HttpListener) for incoming commands whilst updating the server via frequent HTTP requests.
- The device only ever polls the server with HTTP requests. The server uses the response to give the device commands.

The 2nd option seems to be the least secure as the device would have open incoming ports. The 1st option looks the most difficult to reliably implement as it would require low level socket programming. The 3rd option seems easy and secure but due to the latency requirements the device would need to poll every few seconds. This impacts the scalability of the system.

So at what frequency does HTTP polling create more overhead than just constantly keeping a TCP connection open? 5s? 3s? 1s? Or am I overstating the overhead of keeping a TCP connection open in ASP.NET? Or is there a completely different way that this can be implemented?

Thanks.

Comment: An open incoming port by itself is not more or less secure than when it is closed by itself.

Comment: I'm not an expert on embedded device security, but I remember reading an article that said that having open inbound ports increases your exposure by giving attackers one more vector to get at the device, especially if the device is using outdated / unsupported network drivers.

Comment: I never said it cannot be a problem. I just said that opening a port isn't going to be magically insecure by itself. Even if it is going to insecure it is not the fact that the port is open, but because there is some service listening on the port. An open port by itself cannot do anything. The moment you understand that fact you are half way finding out whether it is less secure for your situation.

Comment: I understand that the actual service listening to the port will have more impact than the fact that the port itself is open. I'm intending to use X509 certs / SSL etc. to ensure authenticity. My only concern would be an undiscovered bug somewhere in the network stack of the device that might compromise it. Presumably vulnerabilities like these would be easier to exploit remotely if the device had listening ports.

Answer (score 2):

> So at what frequency does HTTP polling create more overhead than just constantly keeping a TCP connection open? 5s? 3s? 1s?

There is nothing to do to keep a TCP connection open. The only thing you might need to do is to use TCP keep-alive (which have nothing to do with HTTP keep-alive!) in case you want to keep the connection idle (i.e no data to send) for a long time.

with HTTP your overhead already starts with the first request, since your data need to be encapsulated into a HTTP message. This overhead can be comparable small if the message is large or it can easily be much larger than the message itself for small messages. Also, HTTP server close the TCP connection after some idle time so you might need to re-establish the TCP connection for the next data exchange which is again overhead and latency.

HTTP has the advantage to pass through most firewalls and proxies, while plain TCP does not. You also get encryption kind of free with HTTPS, i.e. there are established standards for direct encrypted connection and for tunneling through a proxy.

WebSockets is something in between: you do a HTTP request and then upgrade HTTP to WebSocket. The initial overhead is thus as large as for HTTP but for the next messages the overhead is not that much higher than TCP. And you can do also WebSockets with HTTPS (i.e. wss:// instead of ws://). It passes through most simple firewalls and proxies, but more deeper inspection firewalls might still have trouble with it.

Setting up a TCP listener will be a problem if you have your IoT device behind some NAT router, i.e. the usual setup inside private or SoHo networks. To reach the device one would need to open a tunnel at the router from outside into the network, either by administrating the router by hand or with UPnP (which is often switched off for security reasons).  So you would introduce too much problems for the average user.

Which means that the  thing which the fewest problems for the customer is probably HTTP polling. But this is also the one with the highest overhead. Still mostly compatible are WebSockets which have less overhead and more problems but even less overhead can be reached with simple TCP to the server. TCP listener instead would cause too much trouble.

As for resources on the server side: each HTTP polling request might use new TCP connection but you can also reuse an existing one. In this case you could decide between more overhead and latency one the client side (new TCP connection for each request) which needs few resources on the server side and less overhead and latency on the client side which needs more resources on the server side (multiple HTTP requests per TCP connection). With WebSockets and plain TCP connection you always need more server side resources, unless your client will automatically re-establish the connection on loss of connectivity.

Comment: I hadn't realised the problems that a TCP listener could cause with firewalls, networks etc. Thanks for excluding that option. I think a keep-alive request or SignalR might be the solution.

Answer (score 2):

These days you should use a IOT Specific communication protocol over TLS 2.0 for secure light weight connections. For example AWS uses MQTT http://mqtt.org/ and Azure uses AMQP https://www.amqp.org/

The idea is you get a broker you can connect to securely then you use a messaging protocol with a topic to route messages to the proper devices. Also IBM has been using MQTT for a long time and routers now typically come with port 8883 open which is MQTT over TLS.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use SignalR to connect client and server. It provides you minimal latency without polling. The API is very simple to use.

Physically, this runs over WebSockets which are scalable to a large number of concurrent connections. If you don't have a need for more than 100k per Windows server this would not be a concern.

Comment: SignalR would be a good solution, I'll have a look for a working .NET MF client.